# Drupal views, show 'add to cart' button instead of ''Register now'

Tags: civievent

I would like show 'add to cart' button instead of ''Register now' for a drupal views I have created for upcoming events, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can rewrite the register now link  to or add custom text field with rewrite link as

```
https://domain.org/civicrm/event/add_to_cart?reset=1&id=[event_id]
```

to remove from cart

```
https://domain.org/civicrm/event/remove_from_cart?reset=1&id=[event_id]
```

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: thanks but [event_id] doesnt seem to render. any tips?

Comment: also, can the add_to_cart and remove_from_cart be automatically appear/disappear in views, depending on whichever is selected?

Comment: by [event_id] i meant to add event id field and exclude from display and replace [event_id] with the token found in replacement pattern

Comment: Nope the view won't do it automatically you can do it by using views conditional  check participant status for the event. If pending cart than show remove from cart else add to cart